# I'm not using a variable but it occours a TypeError

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror

I'm using opencv3 but it occoured a TypeError
It's real confuse that I didnt call it...

```
----------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/2018091001/OneDrive/Python/VOD/Ocv.py", line 52, in <module>
    similarity = cv2.compareHist(H1,models[x][0],0)
TypeError: H2 is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Answer (score 2):

Code rarely knows the names of variables unless it named them. That is, `cv2.compareHist` doesn't know what you named your variables; *it* named an argument `H2`, and it's complaining about *that* argument.

Specifically, [the prototype for `compareHist` is](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=comparehist#cv2.compareHist):

```
cv2.compareHist(H1, H2, method) → retval
```

So the error is telling you that the second argument you passed (`models[x][0]`) is of incorrect type. Since you haven't shown us your code, that's the best I can give you; you need to pass a `numpy` array or scalar as the second argument.